# Android JSON API is missing append function (for adding json arrays)

Tags: android, json

I have some Java code that I want to start using with Android - it uses the org.json library which has been part of the Android API since the beginning.

I'm finding a few differences between the standard implementation at json.org, and the Android implementation, which is not a surprise - perhaps the Android version is older.

But the lack of the append function is different.   It is preferred over the accumlate function and the Android documentation for accumulate explicitly states why you should use append instead:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#accumulate(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

And yet the append function is missing both from the docs and the library itself.

For the record, [here's the function](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#append(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) at json.org.

So, I'm puzzled: this would seem to be a bug since Android's beginning and I see no mention of it anywhere.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I'm not 'missing something' - that the function is missing - it is simple to just copy json.org's version of the missing function.

You can't substitute json.org's implementation in place of course, since the package names would clash, but you can stick their implementation of the missing function somewhere in your code.  Note that I editing it to remove testValidity which is also missing from Android, and add the 'subject'.

```
public static JSONObject append( JSONObject subject, String key, java.lang.Object value) throws JSONException {
    Object object = subject.opt(key);
    if (object == null) {
        subject.put(key, new JSONArray().put(value));
    } else if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
        subject.put(key, ((JSONArray) object).put(value));
    } else {
        throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + key + "] is not a JSONArray.");
    }
    return subject;
}
```

Note that they have their own, permissive, license, excepting that you can't use it for evil!

> /*  Copyright (c) 2002 JSON.org
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy  of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal  in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell  copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is  furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY,  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS
>   BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
>   ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,  OUT OF OR IN
>   CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE 
>   SOFTWARE.  */